# why is everything i type underlined in red

Tags: 20.04, word-documents

[image][WPS Writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVifg.png)

Why is this happen? It typing in red color and underlined.

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu? [Edit] your question accordingly

Comment: WPS Office is a light-weight office for Linux

Comment: ask ubuntu is a Q&A site for questions related to ubuntu. Please read [ask] then edit your question accordingly

Comment: thank you @24601. I found a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Review tab, turn Track Changes OFF.[image]